# Javascript/CSS - Clip image to container while dragging/panning and scaling/zooming

Tags: javascript, css, image, drag-and-drop, overflow

I want to be able to drag and zoom an image, but hide the overflow beyond the limits of the images container. Here is the basic setup:

```
<div class="region-device-images-modal">
  <img id="device_model_image" src="{src}">
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.region-device-images-modal {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;

.region-device-images-modal>img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
```

which initially loads the image like this:

[image: Initial Load]
When the user begins to drag or zoom I add this CSS to the image:

```
transform: scale(4);
position: absolute;
left: -127.25px;
top: -1111.59px
```

However the CSS overflow property is then ignored and the image is shown beyond the limits of the container div. I want the image overflow to be hidden. Here is what it looks like, and I want the circled yellow portion to be hidden:

[image]

What I would like to see is this:

[image]

Comment: Can you make an example here? https://codepen.io/pen/

Comment: https://codepen.io/ngoodwin/pen/poQyNdY  It works as expected in the codepen, could is be becuase this is inside a modal in my application?

Comment: The code pen seems to be incomplete, If you want to share a dummy git repository with the example, it would be good to see it happening to try to find the problem

Comment: @paulo fernando that won't be possible I don't think, we are using backbone.js, and injecting React 15 components into the view and this issue is happening in a ReactBootstrap modal within all the framework. I think this is a CSS issue anyway, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: I see, what component are you using for the drag and drop?

Comment: Not drag and drop, just zooming and panning using CSS, see the css transform and the position absolute rules above

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, was missing position: relative in the parent div. Could have sworn it was there!